# Is it always possible to generate matrices B and C, when given A, so that BAC is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

If only matrix $A$ is known (with either $rank(A)=2$ or $rank(A)=3$), and
$A \in \mathbb{R}^{3x3}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{4x3}, C \in \mathbb{R}^{3x4}$, is it always possible to find matrices $B$ and $C$, so that $BAC$ will have a non-zero determinant?

Could you, please, provide some guidance / hints as to how to approach the generation of $B$ and $C$ if this is possible?

Comment: What if $A$ is the zero matrix?

Comment: It's impossible *ever* to have $BAC$ invertible, since $\operatorname{rk}(BAC) \le \operatorname{rk}(A) \le 3< 4$.whereas the product is $4\times 4$.

Comment: This thing can never be invertible since $B$ is not surjective.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never possible, as the rank of $BAC$ is at most the maximum of the ranks of $B$, $A$ and $C$, and so the rank of $BAC$ is at most three and the determinant of this $4\times 4$ matrix is zero.

Comment: The rank is *at most* three.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Of course, thank you @amsmath for pointing out my imprecision. Fixed now.